# pip не является внешней или внутренней командой / папка Script пустая, в переменной окружения все прописано

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip

Всем привет, в консоли вылезает ошибка

> pip не является внешней или внутренней командой, исполняемой программой или пакетным файлом

при установке ставил галочку у пункта "Add Python to PATH", также пробовал ставить питон в корень диска C в специально созданную папку python, в переменной окружения все прописано корректно. Ничего не помогает. Насколько я понял у меня проблема в том, что папка Script пустая.

Comment: python3 -m pip install pip

Answer (score 1):

У меня на python 3.8 (последняя для win7) заработало после действий:

0. удалил питон и почистил от него папки где он был
1. установку питона производил со всеми галочками в установщике, он там докачивал с инета нужные ему компоненты
2. проверил системный путь чтобы было

> "C:\soft\python387;C:\soft\python387\Scripts;"

"soft" это путь к питону у меня

3. потом обновил pip "`c:\soft\python387\python.exe -m pip install --upgrade pip`"

Comment: Теперь пишет "-m" не является внутренней или внешней командой

Comment: 0) юзер админские права имеет?
 
1) в командной строке "pip" что пишет?